# JavaFx: TreeTableView weird NullpointerException

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, javafx-8, treetableview

I have noticed a weird NPE in the `TreeTableView`

It happens if you doubleClick in the table where there is no row present. Ill attach a screenshot to show what I mean exactly.

I comes purely from JavaFx it has nothing to do with my code. I also did a research and didn't find anything related to this.

Here is a simple code to reproduce it:

Controller:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private TreeTableColumn<Model, String> column;
    @FXML
    private TreeTableView<Model> treeTable;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        TreeItem<Model> root = new TreeItem<>(new Model("Root"));
        treeTable.setRoot(root);
        column.setCellValueFactory(value -> value.getValue().getValue().textProperty());

    }

    private class Model {
        private StringProperty text;

        Model(String text) {
            this.text = new SimpleStringProperty(text);
        }

        public StringProperty textProperty() {
            return text;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text.get();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getText();
        }
    }
}
```

.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="stackoverflow.treeview.Controller">
    <TreeTableView fx:id="treeTable">
        <columns>
            <TreeTableColumn fx:id="column" text="Test"/>
        </columns>
    </TreeTableView>
</AnchorPane>
```

If you double click in the red region a NPE is thrown.

[image]

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TreeTableRowBehavior.handleClicks(TreeTableRowBehavior.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.simpleSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:259)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TableRowBehaviorBase.doSelect(TableRowBehaviorBase.java:120)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.mousePressed(CellBehaviorBase.java:150)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TableRowBehaviorBase.mousePressed(TableRowBehaviorBase.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:95)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Java version: 1.8u121**

As a solution I would accept any workaround which really works or any explanation/javafx bug-report which shows they are working on it or there is a fix in a following version.

Comment: Well, a pretty bad work around would be to simply catch the exception and handle it.

Comment: it's a bug in treeTableRowBehavior.handleClicks (seen in fx11) - the code can't cope with empty rows .. you might consider reporting it :)

Comment: as a hackaround, you might try to register an eventFilter on a custom row that consumes the event if it's a doubleClick

Comment: @kleopatra I've tried it, but same NPE. You mean this way: https://pastebin.com/TvT29PPU ?

Comment: Note you can submit a bug report [here](https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/).

Comment: you need to intercept the pressed as slaw shows in his answer. It's helpful to read the sources - just saying :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click in the empty space, where there's no columns, you end up clicking on a `TreeTableRow`. Apparently there is a bug in the control's behavior class that means it can't handle rows with `null` items. You don't see this bug if you click in the empty space *of a column* because that clicks on a `TreeTableCell`, whose behavior class does not seem to suffer from the same problem. Not sure where the exact difference is, but I only quickly glanced at the source code.

One way to stop the exception being thrown, as @kleopatra mentioned, is to add an event filter to the `TreeTableRow` that consumes double clicks on empty rows.

```
var table = new TreeTableView<String>();
table.setRowFactory(ttv -> {
    var row = new TreeTableRow<String>();
    row.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> {
        if (row.getItem() == null && event.getClickCount() % 2 == 0) {
            event.consume();
        }
    });
    return row;
});
```

*Note: You need `clickCount % 2 == 0` because the behavior class will try to access the `TreeItem` when the click count is even.*

Comment: Wow, thanks both the explanation and the answer :)  Sill would you suggest reporting it?

Comment: yeah, of course - bugs that are not known to the dev team are rarely fixed :)

Comment: btw, there's a drawback to this hack: due to being a filter, the double pressed will never reach an empty treeTableCell - so custom cell implementations can't do anything fancy with empty cells. My guess is, that's rather seldom - but should be kept in mind

Comment: thanks for reporting :) https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8222454